# Differences in extracted values after projecting raster

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, exact-extract

I am trying to project a raster to EPSG:3035 to match the CRS of the grid file on which it should be extracted to.

I use this code:

```
NDVI_2005 <- raster("data_Raster/Greenness/mosaic2005_2006.tif")
NDVI_2005 <- NDVI_2005 %>% 
  projectRaster(NDVI_2005, crs="EPSG:3035")

countryGrids$NDVI_2005 <- exact_extract(NDVI_2005, countryGrids, 'mean')
```

But R will show the following warning message upon extraction:

```
Warning message in .local(x, y, ...):
“Polygons transformed to raster CRS (EPSG:NA)”
```

Then I tried removing the pipe syntax and instead projecting like this:

```
NDVI_2005 <- projectRaster(NDVI_2005, crs="EPSG:3035")
```

Now the warning message doesn't show when I run the extraction, but I noticed the values of the variable NDVI_2005 can be quite different, often by more than just a few decimal points. My question is, why do the values differ when projecting the raster with or without the pipe syntax, and what is the 'correct' way to project the raster?

Comment: Apart from the excellent answer below, you should consider use the `terra` package instead of `raster`. Most of the function you used in your analysis have more or less the same syntax, so a simple Google search will help you migrate to `terra`.

Comment: [This vignette](https://rspatial.org/pkg/index.html) might also be helpful in case you are interested in `{terra}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the "pipe" operator, it puts the thing on the left as the first argument of the function call on the right. You are doing:

```
NDVI_2005 <- NDVI_2005 %>% 
  projectRaster(NDVI_2005, crs="EPSG:3035")
```

which means you are effectively doing:

```
NDVI_2005 <- projectRaster(NDVI_2005, NDVI_2005, crs="EPSG:3035")
```

ie you have effectively put `NDVI_2005` **twice** in the function call.

That's why its different to what you did without the pipe operator:

```
NDVI_2005 <- projectRaster(NDVI_2005, crs="EPSG:3035")
```

You'll have to check the help for `projectRaster` to see what it does in this case, but its quite likely the source of the problem.

I'll add this to my long list of reasons to avoid the pipe operator.